# How to throw custom exception in Optional

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java-8, option-type

The orignal code is

```
if(object==null){
  throw new CustomException(ErrorEnum.OBJECT_NULL)
}
```

now I want to use `Optional` to handle `NullPointerException`.
Just like this

```
Optional.ofNullable(object).orElseThrow(()->{throw new CustomException(ErrorEnum.OBJECT_NULL);}
```

But doing this makes code much longer than original. Maybe I should use the first way to solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, Optional is totally unnecessary here. The first way is better.

Comment: note, you're expected to supply the desired exception, not to throw it. `orElseThrow(()->{throw new CustomException(ErrorEnum.OBJECT_NULL);}` can be simplified to `orElseThrow(()-> new CustomException(ErrorEnum.OBJECT_NULL)`

Comment: That said, in this particular, I'd go with the first approach. optionals are useful when they're used correctly, in this case, there is no need to use it.

Comment: You shouldn't create and throw away an optional inside a method. The if is shorter, more readable, and more efficient in terms of performance and memory. Only use optionals a return values for methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with commenters and other answers who are saying that `Optional` is unnecessary here. Indeed, it echoes advice I've also given elsewhere. In this case if one *already has* a nullable variable `object` then it's rather roundabout to wrap it in an `Optional` just to throw an exception, and as you observe, it's longer than the original.

The question to ask instead is, where did the reference in `object` come from? Did it come from another method that returns a nullable reference? If so, then perhaps that other method should be refactored to return `Optional<T>` instead of a nullable reference of type `T`.

Comment: Actually `object`comes from `ObjectDao`,after reading your answer.i think i should refactored all query methods to return Optional<T>.But I want to know if this is reasonable.

Answer (score 21):

```
Optional.ofNullable(object).orElseThrow(() -> new CustomException(ErrorEnum.OBJECT_NULL));
```

If you read the method definition in [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) javadoc

```
public <X extends Throwable> T orElseThrow(Supplier<? extends X> exceptionSupplier) throws X extends Throwable
```

This shows that you require a Supplier of X where X extends Throwable.
[Supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) is an interface with a method `get`. Since it has only 1 abstract method, its a Functional Interface which you can instantiate using Lambda expressions.

Since it takes no parameter we will do `() -> new CustomException("your error message");` This creates an instance of `Supplier` which returns a CustomException object when `get` is invoked which I am passing as the parameter to the `orElseThrow`.

Having said all that, you should not use Optional for this use case as it provides no benefit to you.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 9):

Optionals are intended as a safer alternative than a reference of type `T` that refers to an object or `null`, but it's only safer or better if you use it correctly. Both the examples given are safe but it's not better to use an Optional to solely replace an `if` statement as shown.

Also, note that you're expected to supply the desired exception, not to throw it. i.e.

```
orElseThrow(() ->{throw new CustomException(ErrorEnum.OBJECT_NULL);}
```

should be

```
orElseThrow(() ->{return new CustomException(ErrorEnum.OBJECT_NULL);}
```

or better

```
orElseThrow(() -> new CustomException(ErrorEnum.OBJECT_NULL));
```

That said, in this particular, I'd go with the first approach. optionals are useful when they're used correctly, i.e as a method return type to wrap a value that may or may not be present as well as code documentation. Thus, in this case, there is no need to use it.